# Big confusion about cohomology of complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

First, I never learned complex manifold properly (I am more familiar with complex variety) hence the questions will be very elementary. I apologise for this.

Let $X$ be a complex smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Then the singular cohomology of $X$ with complex coefficient has top degree $2n$.

Also, we can consider holomorphic de Rham cohomology of $X$. In this case, top degree is $n$.

How can they coincide if de Rham cohomology only tells about the even degree?

So my question is that how are holomorphic de Rham cohomology and singular cohomology with complex coefficient related.

Also, where can I get more information about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the usual de Rham and singular cohomology coincide (see Ch.4 of Voisin). As for holomorphic de Rham and singular, the hypercohomology of the holomorphic de Rham complex and the singular cohomology coincide (see Ch. 8 of Voisin)

Comment: @daruma Okay, so I overheard wrong then. Thank you for the reference!

Comment: Another keyword is Dolbeault cohomology.

Comment: The first chapter of Griffiths-Harris should help you clarify some of your doubts, I encourage you to read it thoroughly.